# route to adresses with same structure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm new to MVC and web dev, I have the following routes:

```
        //"/display/flight1/4" - upload frm flight1 file, show as animation(4 times in a sec), show end alert
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "uploadPlaneData",
            url: "display/{fileName}/{times}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Display", action = "UploadPlaneData", fileName = "flight1", times = 4 }
        );

        //"/display/127.0.0.1/5400" - check plane place(port 5400 ip 127.0.0.1)(lat, lon) and show a plane icon on the map
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "showPlaneIcon",
            url: "display/{ip}/{port}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Display", action = "ShowPlaneIcon", ip = "127.0.0.1", port = 5402 }
        );
```

The problem is that if I'm trying to navigate to the second page, it shows  me the first one. and I'm putting the second above the first in code, then it's navigating to the one top, my question is how can I navigate to `/display/127.0.0.1/5400` and to `/display/flight1/4`

Comment: Sorry for not being able to give a good answer. I typically use attribute routing, so I'm not really familiar with MVC routing. I made the mistake of assuming it's the same.

Comment: @John I did same as the link that you gave, (I added regex in both routes), and now it works, thanks for help

Comment: if you add an answer I'll upvote it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `regular expressions` for the attributes in both the routes. For instance:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "uploadPlaneData",
    url: "display/{fileName}/{times}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Display", action = "UploadPlaneData", fileName = "flight1", times = 4 },
    constraints: new { fileName = @"\w+", times = @"\d+" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "showPlaneIcon",
    url: "display/{ip}/{port}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Display", action = "ShowPlaneIcon", ip = "127.0.0.1", port = 5402 },
    constraints: new { ip = @"\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b", port = @"\d+" }
);
```